# Creating anonymous block on Postgres to update rows

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I ran this anonymous block on Postgres and got this error:

```
DO
$$BEGIN
    FOR diag_file IN 
        SELECT d_file.diagnostic_file_id AS diagnostic_file_id, 
            controller.controller_id AS controller_id
        FROM diagnostic_file d_file
        JOIN decoder_mapping d_mapping ON d_mapping.decoder_mapping_id = d_file.decoder_mapping_id
        JOIN device_model d_model ON d_model.device_model_id = d_mapping.device_model_id
        JOIN controller ON controller.device_model_id = d_model.device_model_id
        WHERE d_file.controller_id IS NULL
    LOOP
        UPDATE diagnostic_file SET controller_id = diag_file.controller_id WHERE diagnostic_file.diagnostic_file_id = diag_file.diagnostic_file_id;
        COMMIT;
    END LOOP;
END;$$;
```

An It returns me this error:

```
WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress

Query 1 OK: COMMIT
```

Comment: Hard to believe... Can you come up with a reproducible test case; something I can tun on my database?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Did you mean data structure?

Comment: Why use PL/pgSQL and a slow and inefficient loop at all?

Comment: 1) Where is `diag_file` declared? 2) Where is `DO.controller_id` coming from?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver was something bad when typing the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you refferme some other way?

Comment: [That code should not run in Postgresql 9.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nel_aqlZ). Are you sure the version is correct?

Comment: Still not seeing where you declare `diag_file`?

Answer (score 2):

> An It returns me this error:
>
> `WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress`

Not an error, a warning. You tried to commit, but there's no transaction.

Often this happens when you've turned on `autocommit` and then `commit`. It's warning you that the commit does nothing.

---

[Your loop should not work at all in PostgreSQL 9.5](https://dbfiddle.uk/Nel_aqlZ), you can't begin nor end transactions inside PL/pgSQL in that version. THat is not introduced until PostgreSQL 11.

```
ERROR:  cannot begin/end transactions in PL/pgSQL
HINT:  Use a BEGIN block with an EXCEPTION clause instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 11 at SQL statement
```

---

If you're writing a loop in SQL, you can probably do it easier and faster without the loop. In this case with an update from a sub-select.

```
update diagnostic_file set controller_id = diag_file.controller_id
from (
  SELECT d_file.diagnostic_file_id AS diagnostic_file_id, 
         controller.controller_id AS controller_id
  FROM diagnostic_file d_file
  JOIN decoder_mapping d_mapping ON d_mapping.decoder_mapping_id = d_file.decoder_mapping_id
  JOIN device_model d_model ON d_model.device_model_id = d_mapping.device_model_id
  JOIN controller ON controller.device_model_id = d_model.device_model_id
  WHERE d_file.controller_id IS NULL
) diag_file
WHERE diagnostic_file.diagnostic_file_id = diag_file.diagnostic_file_id
```

The [update docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-update.html) have many examples.